# Установить значение глобальной переменной

Tags: javascript, canvas, javascript-events, type-error

Нужно задать значение глобальной переменной , которая отслеживается в одном файле, а меняется в другом. Пробовал так:

1.js:

```
    window.storage.x = {
        aInternal: '',
        aListener: function(val) {},
        set a(val) {
            this.aInternal = val;
            this.aListener(val);
        },
        get a() {
            return this.aInternal;
        },
        registerListener: function(listener) {
            this.aListener = listener;
        }
    }

        window.storage.x.registerListener(function(val) {
            console.log('change on'+window.storage.x.a);
        });

     window.storage.x.a = 'blue';
```

2.js.

```
function main_canvas_down(e) {

if (_disable_interaction)
    return;

if (e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();

var x = m_mouse.get_coords_x(e);
var y = m_mouse.get_coords_y(e);

var obj = m_scenes.pick_object(x, y);

if (obj){
    console.log(m_scenes.get_object_name(obj));
}
if (m_scenes.get_object_name(obj) == 'Cylinder.003'){
     window.storage.x.a='green';
}else if(m_scenes.get_object_name(obj) == 'Cylinder.002'){
    window.storage.x.a='red';
}else if(m_scenes.get_object_name(obj) == 'Cylinder.001'){
    window.storage.x.a='purple';
}else if(m_scenes.get_object_name(obj) == 'Cylinder.000'){
    window.storage.x.a='blue';
}}
```

Но получаю ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в ошибке ясно по человеческий написано все что вам надо

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов  я не могу понять почему "undefined"

Comment: он не видит переменную  `a` а вы пытаетесь присвоить этому `а` свойство.Теперь понятно ?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов Понятно, только почему он её не видит, раз это глобальная переменная? Я ж инициализировал eё в 1.js

Comment: я не вижу там глобальную переменную

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов я использую "window.storage" как хранилище переменной, или это неправильно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97187/discussion-between-ctaco23-and--).

Comment: сделайте ваш пример воспроизводимым

Comment: А где у Вас определяется собственно `window.storage`?

Comment: @Yaant в 1.js вот так: window.storage={}